# Making the objectheader sticky and rest of the page scrollable

Tags: html, css, xml, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a page with an ObjectHeader and 4 panels. All the panels have a table with a horizontal scrollbar. I want to freeze the object header at the top whenever the page is scrolled. I tried the sticky property but it is not applicable for ObjectHeader but it is applicable to IconTab Bar. But in my case, I can't use IconTab Bar. I also tried some CSS but failed Please help. Below is my XML code.

XML Code :

```
<mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns="sap.m"
controllerName="sap.hmel.pymt.adv.controller.PaymentAdviceApp" displayBlock="true">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page showHeader="false" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onCallPayAdvice">
            <ObjectHeader  title="" fullScreenOptimized="true" >
                <attributes>
                    <ObjectAttribute title="Total Credit Values" text="+ ₹ {credModel>/header/TotalCreditItem}"/>
                    <ObjectAttribute title="Total Debit Values" text="- ₹ {credModel>/header/TotalDebitItem}"/>
                    <ObjectAttribute title="Balance" text=" ₹ {credModel>/header/TotalBalance}"/>
                </attributes>
                <statuses>
                    <ObjectStatus title="Selected Credit Values" text="+ ₹ {detail>/crdTotal}" state="{detail>/utrState}"/>
                    <ObjectStatus title="Selected Debit Values" text="- ₹ {detail>/invTotal}" state="{detail>/totalState}"/>
                    <ObjectStatus title="Balance" text=" ₹ {detail>/balance} {detail&gt;/Waers}" state="{detail>/balState}"/>
                </statuses>
            </ObjectHeader>


            <Panel expandable="true" headerText="Payment Document ( Subtotal : + ₹ {credModel>/header/PaymentSum})" class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin"
                id="paymentPanel">
                <ScrollContainer vertical="true">
                    <Table class="sapUiLargeMarginBottom" items="{credModel>/Payment}" growingThreshold="5" fixedLayout="false" id="paymentDocument"
                        growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" inset="false" mode="MultiSelect" selectionChange="onRowSelectionChangePayment">
                        <columns>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem id="columnTempId">
                                <cells>

                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
                </ScrollContainer>
            </Panel>
            <Panel expandable="true" headerText="Credit Note (Subtotal : + ₹ {credModel>/header/CreditSum})" class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin">
                <ScrollContainer vertical="true">
                    <Table sticky="HeaderToolbar,ColumnHeaders" class="sapUiLargeMarginBottom" items="{credModel>/Credit}" id="creditNote" growing="true"
                        growingScrollToLoad="true" growingThreshold="5" mode="MultiSelect" selectionChange="onRowSelectionChangeCredit">
                        <columns>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem id="column">
                                <cells>
                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
                </ScrollContainer>
            </Panel>
            <Panel expandable="true" headerText="Invoice (Subtotal : - ₹ {credModel>/header/InvoiceSum})" class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin">
                <ScrollContainer vertical="true">
                    <Table class="sapUiLargeMarginBottom" items="{credModel>/Invoice}" fixedLayout="false" id="invoice" growingThreshold="5" growing="true"
                        growingScrollToLoad="true" inset="false" mode="MultiSelect" selectionChange="onRowSelectionChange">
                        <columns>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem id="columnTemp">
                                <cells>
                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
                </ScrollContainer>
            </Panel>
            <Panel expandable="true" headerText="Debit Note (Subtotal : - ₹ {credModel>/header/DebitSum})" class="sapUiMediumMarginBegin">
                <ScrollContainer vertical="true">
                    <Table class="sapUiLargeMarginBottom" items="{credModel>/Debit}" growingThreshold="5" fixedLayout="false" id="debitNote" growing="true"
                        growingScrollToLoad="true" inset="false" mode="MultiSelect" selectionChange="onRowSelectionChangeDebit">
                        <columns>
                            </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem id="columnId">
                                <cells>
                                    </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
                </ScrollContainer>
            </Panel>
            <footer>
                <Bar>
                    <contentRight>
                        <Button text="Create" type="Accept" id="btnCreateId" press="onCreate"/>
                        <Button text="Cancel" type="Reject" icon="sap-icon://decline" press="onCancel"/></contentRight>
                </Bar>
            </footer>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

Comment: Have you looked into `sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout`? It provides sticky ObjectHeader and sections out of the box. If you target Fiori UX, I'd strongly encourage to replace the current implementation with the ObjectPageLayout. See the underlying topics in https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/de713373c4ef4e53b5717c59ed2c8d64 and samples in Demo Kit.